# How to remove selected characters from a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace

I have been trying to learn how I can remove special characters on random given strings. A random given string could be something like:

```
uh\n  haha - yes 'nope' \t tuben\xa01337
```

and I have used both regex and `string.translate` to try what could work out for me:

```
import re

random_string = "uh\n  haha - yes 'nope' \t tuben\xa01337"

print(re.sub(r"/[' \n \t\r]|(\xa0)/g", '', random_string))
print("-------")
print(random_string.translate(str.maketrans({c: "" for c in "\n \xa0\t\r"})))
```

The output of that returns:

```
uh
  haha - yes 'nope'      tuben 1337
-------
uhhaha-yes'nope'tuben1337
```

The problem is that it does not work as I wanted since I want a output to be:

```
uh haha - yes nope tuben 1337
```

I wonder how I could be able to do that?

- \n\t\xa0 or any similar should be replaced as one whitespace
- ' and " should be replaced with no whitespace, just remove the ' and "
- double whitespaces or more should be replaced with only one whitespace total. Meaning that if there are two or more whitespaces in a text they should be replaced with one.
- Any special characters should be removed as well

Comment: Python regular expressions don't have `/` around them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regular expression will do the trick:

```
>>> print(re.sub(" +", ' ', re.sub(r'''/|[^\w\s]|\n|\t|\r|(\xa0)/g''', '', random_string)))
uh haha yes nope tuben 1337
```

The outer `re.sub` matches multiple whitespace and replaces it with one whitespace.

The inner `re.sub` is almost identical to the one you're using, I just found it more readable to have them all as choices with `|`.

Comment: This was pretty nice! I assume I can then create any myself any characters I want to be replaced inside the | | ? For example `| " |`? That should work as well I believe if I understood it correctly

Comment: Yes, but don't include the spaces, so if you want to replace `"` too then I'd add it behind `'`  like this `|'|"|`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better just replace the special characters (In our case ' and ") by doing something like `[^A-Za-z0-9\s+]|` which removes all the special characters? However by testing it will also remove all the whitespaces but I do believe this would make the code more readable instead of entering all special characters `print(re.sub(" +", ' ', re.sub(r'''/|\n|\t|\r|'|"|(\xa0)|[^A-Za-z0-9]|/g''', '', random_string)))`

Comment: That is correct, however I do seem to fail. Not managed to apply that in the code you have given for example, is there any chance you could help me out with that :(?

Comment: Nevermind! I solved it by doing: `print(re.sub(" +", ' ', re.sub(r'''/|[^\w\s]|\n|\t|\r|(\xa0)/g''', '', random_string)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
import re
random_string = "uh\n  haha - yes 'nope' \t tuben\xa01337"
random_string = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", random_string).strip().replace('"', '').replace("'", '')
print(random_string)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VT2vR8).

**Notes**:

- `re.sub(r"\s+", " ", random_string)` - shrinks any chunks of one or more whitespace chars into a single regular space char
- `.strip()` - removes leading/trailing whitespace
- `.replace('"', '').replace("'", '')` - removes `"` and `'` chars.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> /[' \n \t\r]|(\xa0)/g
> ```

This is syntax that is used by tools like sed or Vim, not Python's `re` module.

The equivalent would be

```
print(re.sub(r"[' \n \t\r]|(\xa0)", '', random_string))
```

which prints

```
uhhaha-yesnopetuben1337
```

which is not far off, but you also removed all spaces.

If you don't remove the spaces,

```
print(re.sub(r"['\n\t\r]|(\xa0)", '', random_string))
```

you get

```
uh  haha - yes nope  tuben1337
```

which has too many spaces.

A solution is to use the *inverse* regular expression (which matches runs of characters you want to *keep*) with `re.findall` to get a list of words, which you can then re-join:

```
result = re.findall(r"[^' \n\t\r\xa0]+", random_string)
print(' '.join(result))
```

which prints

```
uh haha - yes nope tuben 1337
```